# WooCommerce - product_categories shortcode with further filtering

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode

The site I am working on has a few top-level product categories, and each of those have two levels of subcategories.
I have found that to display any subcategories of a parent category, I would use the following shortcode:

```
[product_categories number="-1" parent="##" columns="5" hide_empty="0"]
```

However, I also need to be able to display those same subcategories of a parent category, but only containing products from a certain brand.

> Ex: Category: Clothes ---> Subcategories: Shoes, shirts, pants

In this example, I need to display the subcategories of parent Clothes, however, only the subcategories that contain products from brand (ex: Adidas).

How would I go about this? I know that the `product_categories` shortcode does not have parameters for attributes or tags, so how could I further filter the shortcode without creating the 3 levels of categories for each brand (over 20 brands)?

Thank you!

Running WordPress 4.9.4 and WooCommerce 3.3.0

Comment: I have a very similar problem. Any information on how this was resolved? Custom Query? Is there a way to filter by 2 taxonomies? (category and brand)?